# What is static getDerivedStateFromError in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning about `static getDerivedStateFromError`.

But I couldn't understand when to use `static getDerivedStateFromError` and when  `componentDidCatch`in the component.

The example below what I have tried with both `static getDerivedStateFromError` and `componentDidCatch` but to me they both does the same.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Test extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        hasError: false
      }
   }
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
     return this.props.text != nextProps.text;
   }

   static getDerivedStateFromError(error){
      return { hasError: true }
   }
   componentDidCatch(error, info){
     this.setState({
        hasError: true
     });
   }
   render(){
     const { text } = this.props;
     const { hasError } = this.state;
     return(
       <div>
          {hasError ? <h1>Something went wrong</h1> : <h1>{text}</h1>}
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR - Use `componentDidCatch` for side effects, and `getDerivedStateFromError` to change state and render something different.

Comment: Any knowledge on how return { hasError: true } is updating state inside getDerivedStateFromError?